# How do I ask the user when he/she wants to quit the program

Tags: java

Here's the program that I'm working on but I'm having problems with figuring out how to ask the user if they are done with it by saying a word or number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class paliindrome {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String isPalindrome, reverse = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        PalindromeChecker aGame = new PalindromeChecker();

        System.out.println(" Please type a word and I'll figure out if it's a palindrome(The program is case sensitive).");
        isPalindrome = in.nextLine();


        int length = isPalindrome.length();

        for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            reverse = reverse + isPalindrome.charAt(i);

        if (isPalindrome.equals(reverse))
            System.out.println("The word that you have entered is a palindrome.");
        else
            System.out.println("The word that you have typed isn't a palindrome.");

        char answer;
        do {
            aGame.play ();

            System.out.print("\n Do you want to continue (y or n)?");
            answer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        } while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have the `palindrome` class be separate from your test class where the main() method is located within which you instantiate a `palindrome` object.

Answer (score 1):

Put your entire application within the loop. One easy way would be to default `answer` to `y` (and you can use [`Character.toUpperCase(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-) to eliminate the or) and something like

```
PalindromeChecker aGame = new PalindromeChecker();
char answer = 'y';
while (Character.toUpperCase(answer) == 'Y') {
    String isPalindrome, reverse = "";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    // ... The rest of your code ...
    aGame.play();

    System.out.print("\n Do you want to continue (y or n)?");
    answer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to solve your problem:
Put your entire code in a infinite while loop like this `while(true)`, on the last line of loop just before exiting from the loop, u can ask user if he/she wants to continue. If answer is yes, then use the code `System.exit(0)` to exit from the program or if you want to just break from the loop use `break;` in the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use below code to ask user for quit.

boolean quit = false;
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            do {
                System.out.println("Do you want to quit? (true/false)\n");
                scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                String input = scanner.nextLine();
                quit = Boolean.parseBoolean(input);
            } while (!quit);
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class paliindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String isPalindrome, reverse = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        PalindromeChecker aGame = new PalindromeChecker();
        for (;;) {// or while(true)
            System.out.println(
                    " Please type a word and I'll figure out if it's a palindrome(The program is case sensitive).");
            isPalindrome = in.nextLine();
            int length = isPalindrome.length();

            for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                reverse = reverse + isPalindrome.charAt(i);
            }

            if (isPalindrome.equals(reverse))
                System.out.println("The word that you have entered is a palindrome.");
            else
                System.out.println("The word that you have typed isn't a palindrome.");

            System.out.print("\n Do you want to continue (y or n)?");
            char answer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            if (answer != 'y' && answer != 'Y') {
                break;
            }else{
                aGame.play ();
            }

        }

    }
}
```